# How to check whether a browser app is running on local dev server vs. online staging server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to call a component only on our staging server but not on my local machine:

```html
    <save-drafts-timer v-if="!environment === 'development'" />

    ...

    data () {
      return {
        environment: process.env.NODE_ENV
      }
    }
```

By doing this, will this component be always (and only) called on staging server? If not, is there some reliable way to do that?

Comment: How are you serving your front-end app? We use JADE for example, a template engine; which prints the `process.env.NODE_ENV` somewhere global so we can access it through our scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about your project, but `process.env.NODE_ENV` is a server side environment variable, and Vue is a client side application, so it will not have access to that.

You would have to pass that environment variable to your client somehow. If you are using `webpack`, you could use the `DefinePlugin` feature:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

This will allow you to define a global variable which you could then access inside of Vue.